# Removing duplicate characters from two argument strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc, argv

I'm trying to optimize a problem that I have to make it more readable with the same speed optimization. My problem consists in this:

> Allowed function: **write.c**, nothing else.
>
> Write a program that takes two strings and displays, without doubles, the
>   characters that appear in either one of the strings.
>
> The display will be in the order characters appear in the command line, and
>   will be followed by a \n.

As you can see, in the main it will take two of your argument strings (`argv[1]` and `argv[2]`) into our function (`void remove_dup(char *str, char *str2)` after is compiling it with GCC.  That temporary array will hold the ASCII value of the character after a duplicate is detected. For example, `str1 = "hello"` and `str2 = "laoblc"`. The expected output will result as "heloabc" using the write function.

However, GCC was complaining because I have an array subscript with my temporary character array filled in with zeroes from the index of my strings. To stop making the compiler complaint, I had to cast the string index as an int to hold the ASCII value inside my temporary array. This will be our checker, which will determine if there is a duplicate in our string depending on the value of the character. Recompiling it again, but this time using warning flags: `gcc -Wextra -Werror -Wall remove_dup.c`. This is the error that I get:

> remove_dup:11 error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
>
> ```
>            if (temp[str[i]] == 0)
>                      ^~~~~~~
> ```
>
> remove_dup:13 error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
>
> ```
>                    temp[str[i]] = 1;
>                         ^~~~~~~
> ```
>
> remove_dup:21 error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
>
> ```
>            if (temp[str2[i]]  == 0)
>                    ^~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> remove_dup.c:23 error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
>
> ```
>                   temp[str2[i]] = 1;
>                       ^~~~~~~~
> ```

Now my real question is, how can I have the same time efficiency BUT without using any kind of casting into my array? This program is running as `O(m + n)` where `m` is our first string and `n` is our second string.

This is the code:

```
void    remove_dup(char *str, char *str2)
{
    int temp[10000] = {0};
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (temp[(int)str[i]] == 0)
        {
            temp[(int)str[i]] = 1;
            write(1, &str[i], 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (str2[i])
    {
        if (temp[(int)str2[i]]  == 0)
        {
            temp[(int)str2[i]] = 1;
            write(1, &str2[i], 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 3)
        remove_dup(argv[1], argv[2]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

I hope this is clear enough with the logic structure I explained. I might have grammar mistakes, so bear with me :).

Comment: AFAIK casting does not incur a runtime penalty. On a related note, `temp` only needs to be 256 elements long because that's how large `char` is.

Comment: I agree with Schwen. Your code looks good. A slightly more elegant way to remove the annoying gcc warning is to replace `temp[(int)str[i]]` with `temp[+str[i]]`. This will also avoid the explicit cast; it is best to avoid casts whenever possible.

Comment: **Correction**: Unless your chars are `signed`!

Comment: @JosephQuinsey can you explain why chars must be signed in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Casting here will have no performance penalty.

However, as a rule of thumb, it is generally best to avoid explicit casts whenever possible. You can do this by for example by changing:

```
   temp[(int)str[i]]
```

to:

```
   temp[+str[i]]
```

This will work by the usual arithmetic conversions.

However, your code has another problem. You could ask: why would gcc bother to issue such an ***annoying*** warning message?

One answer is that they just like to be annoying. A better guess is that on most platforms `char` is `signed`-- see [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default) --and so if your string happen to have an ASCII char greater than 127 (i.e. less than zero), you will have a bug.

One way to fix this is to replace:

```
   temp[(int)str[i]]
```

with:

```
   temp[str[i] + 128]
```

(and change `int temp[10000] = {0}` to `int temp[256 + 128] = {0}`). This will work regardless of the default sign of `char`.

Comment: As I was testing this, it will not complain. However, it will print both strings with the duplicates. if I make a change for `temp[str[i] + 128]` to `temp[+str[i]]` it will make it work.

Comment: Did you change the _two_ instances of `temp[(int)str[i]]` and the _two_ instances of `temp[(int)str2[i]]`?

Comment: Sorry if the above comment is obvious--I make dumb mistakes sometimes.

Comment: **Edit:** Regarding the OP's comment "This program is running as `O(m * n)` where `m` is our first string and `n` is our second string.", the time is in fact  `O(m + n)`.

Comment: No worries, we all do to be honest. It works fine now after setting both instances to `temp[str[i] + 128]` or `temp[+str[i]]`. I thought to have one instance changed into `temp[+str[i]]` and the other to `temp[str[i] + 128]` will make the same asnwer for both.

Edit: Yes, you are right in the `O(m + n)`. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my real question is, how can I have the same time efficiency BUT without using any kind of casting into my array?

I don't believe casting in C has a runtime penalty. Everything in C is a number anyway. I believe it's just telling the compiler that yes, you know you're using the wrong type and believe it's ok.

Note that `char` can be signed. It is possible for a negative number to sneak in there.

> This program is running as O(m * n) where m is our first string and n is our second string.

No, it's running as O(n). O(m*n) would be if you were iterating over one string for every character of the other.

```
for( int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < strlen(str2); j++ ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But you're looping over each string one after the other in two independent loops. This is O(m + n) which is O(n).

---

On to improvements. First, `temp` only ever needs to hold the `char` range which is, at most, `256`. Let's give it a variable name that describes what it does, `chars_seen`.

Finally, there's no need to store a full integer. Normally we'd use [`bool` from `stdbool.h`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C_data_types#/stdbool.h), but we can define our own using `signed char` which is what `stdbool.h` is likely to do. We're sure to wrap it in an `#ifndef bool` so we use the system supplied one if available, it will know better than we do what type to use for a boolean.

```
#ifndef bool
  typedef signed char bool;
#endif
bool chars_seen[256] = {0};
```

You might be able to get a bit more performance by eliminating `i` and instead increment the pointer directly. Not only more performance, but this makes many string and array operations simpler.

```
for( ; *str != '\0'; str++ ) {
    if( !chars_seen[(size_t)*str] ) {
        chars_seen[(size_t)*str] = 1;
        write(1, str, 1);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm casting to [`size_t`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C_data_types#/Size_and_pointer_difference_types), not `int`, because that is the proper type for an index.

You might be able to shave a touch off by using post-increment, whether this helps is going to depend on your compiler.

```
    if( !chars_seen[(size_t)*str]++ ) {
        write(1, str, 1);
    }
```

Finally, to avoid repeating your code and to extend it to work with any number of strings, we can write a function which takes in the set of characters seen and displays one string. And we'll give the compiler the hint to inline it, though it's of questionable use.

```
inline void display_chars_no_dups( const char *str, bool chars_seen[]) {
    for( ; *str != '\0'; str++ ) {
        if( !chars_seen[(size_t)*str]++ ) {
            write(1, str, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then `main` allocates the array of seen characters and calls the function as many times as necessary.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool chars_seen[256] = {0};

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
      display_chars_no_dups( argv[i], chars_seen );
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```